# Утечки памяти в приложении на erlang'е

Tags: erlang

При работе приложения на erlang'е происходит утечка памяти, сняты следующие метрики:

```
    recon_alloc:memory(usage).
    0.8600619886718996
    18> recon_alloc:memory(used).
    215342352
    19> recon:bin_leak(5).
    [{<0.24.0>,-56,
      [user_drv,
       {current_function,{user_drv,server_loop,6}},
       {initial_call,{user_drv,server,2}}]},
     {<0.3.0>,-11,
      [erl_prim_loader,
       {current_function,{erl_prim_loader,loop,3}},
       {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}]},
     {<0.12.0>,-8,
      [code_server,
       {current_function,{code_server,loop,1}},
       {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}]},
     {<0.33.0>,-2,
      [{current_function,{recon_lib,proc_attrs,2}},
       {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}]},
     {<0.86.0>,-2,
      [{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
       {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]}]
    20> erlang:memory().
    [{total,213730480},
     {processes,3758784},
     {processes_used,3758256},
     {system,209971696},
     {atom,290281},
     {atom_used,286321},
     {binary,196778384},
     {code,5228888},
     {ets,283976}]
```

Хотя 6-ю часами ранее `recon_alloc:memory(usage)` был `0.5`, а `recon_alloc:memory(used)` - около `18000000`, как найти источник утечки?

Comment: Вы бы смотрели в хелп по форматированию, невозможно читать же. А по теме — ну так попробуйте изолировать, упрощайте приложение до тех пор, пока проблема не исчезнет, это поможет найти точку, где начинаются проблемы. Или может быть под ваш рантайм есть memory profiler?

Comment: В большинство своем такое происходит из-за того, что накапливаются сообщения для процессов, которые не обрабатываются ими. Добавьте общий шаблон в каждый ваш воркер и должно стать лучше. Вы используете ETS-таблицы? С ними тоже возможны разные кейсы